# I get "IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 4" when I try to print all groups

Tags: java, regex

I have the code as

```
 String regexpr = "(abc)(ab)(cd)";
 String test = "abcabcd";
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexpr);
 Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
 while(m.find ())
 {
     System.out.println(m.group());
 }
```

This code Gives the output as

```
abcabcd
```

But I want to print all the groups in the matched string i.e

```
group 1 abc
group 2 ab
group 3 cd
```

I tried this

```
int i=1;
while (m.group(i) != null)
{
    System.out.println("group" + i + m.group(i));
    i++;
}
```

I'm getting

```
group 1 abc
group 2 ab
group 3 cd
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 4
```

How can I avoid this exception?

And How can I print the starting and ending Indexes of all  groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the starting and ending Indexes of all the groups by

```
   while (i<=m.groupCount())
       {
           System.out.println("group" + i + m.group(i));
           System.out.println("starting index:" + m.start(i) + "Ending Index:" + m.end(i));
           i++;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when `i` incremented to 4, you're still checking:

```
m.group(i) != null
```

But there's no such group 4.

One solution would be using [`Matcher#groupCount`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount--):

```
while (i < m.groupCount() + 1) {
    System.out.println("group " + i + ": " + m.group(i));
    i++;
}
```

Comment: `i <= m.groupCount()`..:)

Comment: @rock321987 Correct, that's another option.